# How to check the row color in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview

I want to get the `DataGridView` row color in C#.

I have set the background color of a row like this:

```
dgvGrid.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
```

Now I want to get only those rows whose `BackgroundColor` is `LightPink`.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dgvGrid.Rows)
{
    if( /* get the row whose color is pink */)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. However, note that `dgvGrid.Rows` is *not* a collection of `DataRow` - which:

> [Represents a row of data in a DataTable.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Instead, it is a `DataGridViewRowCollection` which is:

> [A collection of DataGridViewRow objects.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

After fixing this in your loop, just check the row color the same way you set it:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvGrid.Rows)
{
    if (row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.LightPink)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
int index = 0;

foreach (var item in ListGV.Rows)
{        
    if (ListGV.Rows[index].BackColor == Color.Pink)                
    {

    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: `foreach` makes no sense here... `item` isn't even used, additional index is needed -> `for` would be way better .. #BetterUndoUsefulEdits

Comment: Well make your own answer here instead of being a smart ass

Comment: this Site is for helping others to get the best solution for their Problem. The sense of it is to get a communtity result to fill all the needs and not various similar answers just because people want to do their individual thing.. A seperate answer with the same content would be meaningless...